# How to write a macro that can take a parameter?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, macros, assert

I want to use some NSAssert stuff and other things to enable better debugging in my app. NSAssert wants a string which it prints if the assertion fails. Nice, but useless unless you type a whole bunch of information in that string, which can become a big mess when done all over the place.

So I want to make a macro that will do the NSAssert call with an string equipped full of useful information like the class name, the method name and other stuff. But more important, I want to provide a custom comment as well. Imagine a macro like this:

USEFUL_ASSERT(foo != nil, @"that wasn't good, really")

for a lot of reasons I can't use a function or method call here, because context would be lost and I could not find out which class caused that problem, which method caused that problem. That can only be done inside that method itself, so I would have to pass a lot of parameters for this information like [self class] and _cmd, but I don't want all this stuff scattered everywhere. The shorter the code to insert, the better to maintain.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you RTFM? (not usually my style, but it *is* your username, afterall)

Comment: man. TFM is so huge, I read all the time. but I'll need another six years until I'm through everything. So I try to accelerate my learning process through SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#define USEFUL_ASSERT(condition, comment) /*whatever*/
```

Comment: Nice, that looks like if I could just use condition, comment in the definition of the macro? gonna try that! perfect.

Comment: Just remember that this is textual replacement, not variable binding, so for example, if you write `USEFUL_ASSERT(++x == 0, @"It's zero")`, that means `x` will be incremented for each occurrence of `condition` in the macro body.

Comment: So, for example, if the macro body is `NSLog(@"%u is true? %@", (condition), (condition) ? @"YES" : @"NO")`, this expands to `NSLog(@"%u is true? %@", (condition), (condition) ? @"YES" : @"NO")`. Notice that there are two `++x` expressions here, so `x` gets incremented twice.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [macro docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments).